Are Bendy bone And Spine IK exportable to UE?
Are Bendy Bones and Spine IK exportable to UE?

Bendy Bones only work in Blender. If you want to export them you need to create a rig that simulates them with a chain of bones. Try https://youtu.be/7s-EFeCSEmo or https://youtu.be/hUdefdwx-CM
